# Chain of Jquery Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise, jquery-chaining

I have  a simple chain of events:

1. Get Columns from a metaData table (async)
2. load selected columns (async)
3. render list

I used to just the chain these functions, each calling the next when it had completed.   However, its not very obvious what's going (calling `getColumnsFromMeta` results in the view being populated).  So in the interest of clarity and code re-use I'd like to refactor these using `JQuery` `Promises`.  I have used promises before.  But how do I chain more than two? `getColumnsFromMeta ().then(loadSourceFromDatabase /*some arguments*/) //.then(renderList)?;`

Here's an example of the `getColumnsFromMeta`:

```
var getColumnsFromMeta = function(id)
{
    var sql,
        dfd;

    dfd = $.Deferred();

    var onSuccess = function(tx, result)
    {
        var columns = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
        {
            columns.push(result.rows.item(i).Column);
        }

        dfd.resolve(columns);
    };

    var onError = function(tx, error)
    {
        dfd.reject(error);
    };

    sql = "SELECT Column FROM Meta WHERE id = ?";

    database.query(sql, [id], onSuccess, onError);

    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
function getColumnsFromMeta()
{
    var d = $.Deferred();

    // retrieve data in async manner and perform
    // d.resolve(columns);

    return d.promise();
}

function loadSelectedColumns(columns)
{
    var d = $.Deferred();

    // retrieve data in async manner and perform
    // d.resolve(data);

    return d.promise();
}

function render(data)
{
    // render your data
}

getColumnsFromMeta().pipe(loadSelectedColumns).pipe(render);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/xYDbm/1/ - here is a working sample

http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/ -- this is the article I really like about promises

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply it works great!  And thanks for the article, it looks good.  As an additional question:  is it possible to chain .done/.always etc on to pipe at different stages?

Comment: @CrimsonChin: yep. PS: give me a second, jsfiddle will be done in a moment

Comment: @CrimsonChin: yes, you can use any of them, as long as `pipe()` returns deferred as well. PS: I added jsfiddle example

Comment: @pcv: it wasn't almost a year ago when I put this answer

Comment: With jQuery 1.8 and later versions, you can replace 'pipe' with 'then' as correctly mentioned by @pcv

Comment: @zerkms: No, but since yours is still the accepted answer, it would still be helpful if you updated it.

Answer (score 4):

zerkms's reply helped me after some thought. I'm going to post what I did here in case an example with full context is helpful.

```
/**
 * takes a list of componentIDs to load, relative to componentRoot
 * returns a promise to the map of (ComponentID -> componentCfg)
 */
function asyncLoadComponents (componentRoot, components) {

    var componentCfgs = {};

    function asyncLoadComponentCfg(component) {
        var url = _.sprintf("%s/%s", componentRoot, component);
        var promise = util.getJSON(url);
        promise.done(function(data) {
            componentCfgs[component] = data;
        });
        return promise;
    }

    var promises = _.map(components, asyncLoadComponentCfg);
    var flattenedPromise = $.when.apply(null, promises);
    var componentCfgPromise = flattenedPromise.pipe(function() {
        // componentCfgs is loaded now
        return $.Deferred().resolve(componentCfgs).promise();
    });

    return componentCfgPromise;
}


var locale = 'en-US';
var componentRoot = '/api/components';
var components = ['facets', 'header', 'DocumentList'];
$.when(asyncLoadComponents(componentRoot, components)).done(function(componentCfgs) {
    buildDocumentListPage(locale, componentCfgs)
});
```